# If father is dead and brothers refuse to act as my nikah wali, what are my options to get married?

Tags: nikah, fiqh, wali

I am in my 40's, never married. I want to get married to someone who my family object to (brothers, as father has passed away). Objections are he is in his 30's, and hasn't been very religious. He wants to change his life, and has returned from Umrah. I believe we could be good for each other as we both come from a similar background, and have same plans for the future to have a more religious base in our lives.

My older brother agreed to be my wali, then asked me to lend him money, which I did. When I stopped, he refused to have anything to do with me. The younger brother dos not want this responsibility. I have spoken to an Imam who said he would mediate, but 2 weeks passed and I have heard nothing. I have never been close to my brothers. I don't believe they want to help, as my mother is very ill and needs looking after, even though there are other family members who can help.

**Question:** I want to know what my options are if my brothers refuse on the grounds that he is not of good character?

I really wanted to be married before my mum passes away. I have had no support. There are no other relatives to turn to for help.

Comment: Welcome to Islam.SE! Questions are expected to be specific, on topic, and with some research done prior to asking. Please refer to [how to ask a question](https://islam.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask), and take a [tour](https://islam.stackexchange.com/tour) in the [help center](https://islam.stackexchange.com/help).